# Emacs: Prefix Command Arguments with numeric Keypad

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Using a french keybord where regular digit are not accessible without holding shift, I would like to use the numpad to be able to send **prefix/numeric arguments** along with emacs commands. 
For instance `M-4 C-b`, `M-6 C-k`, and so on....

Natively, if i try to do so hitting the keypad I get `<M-kp-2> is undefined`.

How can I make it works, either with emacs config, or system settings (using LinuxMint15)?

(I have been through [emacs docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html), but I didn't found any lead)

Answer (score 3):

It's a good question.  Keys such as `<kp-2>` are all bound correctly in `universal-argument-map` to `digit-argument`.  And `<kp-subtract>` is bound to `universal-argument-minus`, etc.  But the Meta modifier is not taught to handle them wrt `universal-argument-map`.

I *think* this is the way to go, but I'm not sure it is the best approach:

```
 (define-key local-function-key-map [M-kp-2] [?\C-2])
```

That works, and it seems parallel to other keypad key bindings in `local-function-key-map`.

BTW, doing this is *not* enough:

```
 (define-key universal-argument-map (kbd "<M-kp-2>") 'digit-argument)
```

Looking forward to other answers. (FWIW, a workaround is to just use `ESC <kp-3>` instead of `<M-kp-3>` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your init file (solution taken from Nicolas Richard message here https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2013-05/msg00365.html):

```lisp
(dotimes (i 10)                         ; for all keys
  (dolist (prefix (list "M" "C"))       ; for both modifiers
    (global-set-key
     (read (format "[%s-kp-%s]" prefix i))
     'digit-argument)
    (put 
     (read (format "%s-kp-%s" prefix i))
     'ascii-character
     (+ ?0 i))))
```

This maps both `C-<kp-num>` and `M-<kp-num>` to the corresponding key bindings with the standard numeric keys.